# Problemas al autenticar laravel 10

Tags: jwt, laravel-10

Estoy usando laravel 10 y jwt, estoy intentando autenticar con una tabla en español con correo y contraseña.

Al registrar un usuario este se registra en la base de datos, pero cuando intento autenticar no es posible. Agregué lo siguiente para que laravel pueda usar la contraseña y correo en lugar de password y email, pero no funcionó y sigue usando los valores por defecto password y email:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'correo'; 
}

public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return 'contrasena';
}
```

Login:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'correo' => 'required|string|email',
        'contrasena' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('correo', 'contrasena');
    
    if (! $token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'No autorizado',
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $customClaims = ['nombre' => $user->nombre, 'correo' => $user->correo];

    $token = $this->jwt->claims($customClaims)->attempt($credentials);

    return response()->json([
        'usuario' => [
            'nombre' => $user->nombre,
            'correo' => $user->correo,
        ],
        'autorizacion' => [
            'token' => $token,
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Register:

```
public function Register(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'correo' => 'required|string|email|unique:usuarios',
        'contrasena' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'nombre' => 'required|string',
        'telefono' => 'required|string|min:10|max:10',
    ]);

    $usuario = new User();
    $usuario->correo = $request->correo;
    $usuario->contrasena = bcrypt($request->contrasena);
    $usuario->nombre = $request->nombre;
    $usuario->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $usuario->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Usuario registrado exitosamente',
    ], 201);
}
```